# How can I programmatically render fullscreen openGL at a specific resolution?

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl

I am working on a OSX/Cocoa graphics application which (for performance reasons) I would like to render at 640x480 when the user selects "full screen" mode. For what it's worth, the content is a custom NSView which draws using openGL.

I understand that rather than actually change the user's resolution, it's preferable to change the backbuffer (as explained on another SO question here: [Programmatically change resolution OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596489/programmatically-change-resolution-os-x)).

Following that advice, I end up with the following two methods (see below) to toggle between fullscreen and windowed. The trouble is that when I go fullscreen, the content does indeed render at 640x480 but is not scaled (IE it appears as if we stayed at the window's resolution and "zoomed" into a 640x480 corner of the render).

I'm probably missing something obvious here - I suppose I could translate the render according to the actual screen resolution to "center" it, but that seems overcomplicated?

```
- (void)goFullscreen{

  // Bounce if we're already fullscreen
  if(_isFullscreen){return;}

  // Save original size and position
  NSRect frame = [self.window.contentView frame];
  original_size = frame.size;
  original_position = frame.origin;

  NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],NSFullScreenModeAllScreens,
                         nil];

  // In lieu of changing resolution, we set the backbuffer to 640x480
  GLint dim[2] = {640, 480};
  CGLSetParameter([[self openGLContext] CGLContextObj], kCGLCPSurfaceBackingSize, dim);
  CGLEnable ([[self openGLContext] CGLContextObj], kCGLCESurfaceBackingSize);

  // Go fullscreen!
  [self enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:options];
  _isFullscreen=true;

}


- (void)goWindowed{

  // Bounce if we're already windowed
  if(!_isFullscreen){return;}

  // Reset backbuffer
  GLint dim[2] = {original_size.width, original_size.height};
  CGLSetParameter([[self openGLContext] CGLContextObj], kCGLCPSurfaceBackingSize, dim);
  CGLEnable ([[self openGLContext] CGLContextObj], kCGLCESurfaceBackingSize);

  // Go windowed!
  [self exitFullScreenModeWithOptions:nil];
  [self.window makeFirstResponder:self];
  _isFullscreen=false;

}
```

## Update

Here's now to do something similar to datenwolf's suggestion below, but not using openGL (useful for non-gl content).

```
// Render into a specific size
renderDimensions = NSMakeSize(640, 480);
NSImage *drawIntoImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:renderDimensions];
[drawIntoImage lockFocus];
[self drawViewOfSize:renderDimensions];
[drawIntoImage unlockFocus];
[self syphonSendImage:drawIntoImage];

// Resize to fit preview area and draw
NSSize newSize = NSMakeSize(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
[drawIntoImage setSize: newSize];
[[NSColor blackColor] set];

[self lockFocus];
[NSBezierPath fillRect:self.frame];
[drawIntoImage drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:self.frame operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1];
[self unlockFocus];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a FBO with a texture of the desired target resolution attached and render to that FBO/texture in said resolution. Then switch to the main framebuffer and draw a full screen quad using the texture rendered to just before. Use whatever magnification filter you like best. If you want to bring out the big guns you could implement a Lancosz / sinc interpolator in the fragment shader to upscaling the intermediary texture.

Comment: That will almost certainly work and it does answer the question as written (thanks). I will probably solve my problem that way for now (and accept the answer) but I'd like to leave the question open a bit longer in case anyone else wants to weigh in. I think ideally I'd prefer to 1. Understand why the backbuffer solution isn't working properly and 2. Be able to do this "the cocoa way" so I can use it on another related project that uses CG rather than GL.

Comment: I updated the question with an example of how to do the functionally equivalent thing in cocoa (useful for non-GL content). It works well enough, but is a bit slow.